# Yii Framework: Putting a chart inside a CJuiTab

Tags: php, yii

I am creating a Portlet with tabs, inside each tab I should place a bar chart. For the moment any chart will do, but I think in the future I will be creating them with Rgraph. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiTabs', array(
                'tabs'=>array(
                        'innovación'=>"ranking",
                        'competitividad'=>"ranking",

                        ),
                // additional javascript options for the tabs plugin
                'options'=>array(
                        'collapsible'=>true,
                ),
            ));
        ?>

   <?php $this->endWidget();?>
```

instead of "ranking" there should be a barchart. I have no idea how to do it and just directly putting html code is messing with other contents in the page. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If is just HTML you can use renderPartial function to render the required html

Answer (score 0):

Cherif is correct but I thought I'd provide some code as I've just done this.

```
    $tabs = array(
        'Tab Heading 1'=>array('id'=>'tab1','content'=>
                $this->renderPartial('_chart1', 
                                array('data1'=>$data1),
                                TRUE)),        
        'Tab Heading 2'=>array('id'=>'tab2','content'=>
                $this->renderPartial('_chart2', 
                                array('data2'=>$data2),
                                TRUE)),        
         );

    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiTabs',array(
        'tabs'=> $tabs,
        // additional javascript options for the tabs plugin
        'options'=>array(
            'collapsible'=>false,
        ),
        'id'=>'MyTabs',
    ));
```

Then in my view folder, I have _chart1.php and _chart2.php, each containing the respective chart widgets.